# Age process of renewal process is a Markov Chain

Tags: probability, self-study, markov-process

If $T_n=\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$ is a renewal process where $X_k$ are identical and independent with values in the positive integers, and $N(t)=\max\{j:T_j\leq t\}$ is the associated counting process, define $C_t=t-T_{N(t)}$ to be the "age" at time $t\in \mathbb{N}$. I'm wondering how to show rigorously  that $C_t$ is a Markov chain.

Heuristically, I can see that $C_{t+1}$ is $C_t+1$ if there is no renewal at $t+1$ and $0$ if there is a renewal at $t+1$, and that the probability of a renewal at $t+1$ should depend on the location of the last renewal and the renewals before that should be irrelevant. But I don't know how to make this "rigorous" or calculate the transition probabilities. So my questions are: what is a rigorous proof that $\{C_t\}$ satisfies the Markov property, and how do you calculate the transition probabilities
\begin{align*}
\Pr(C_{t+1}=i+1|C_t=i),\\
\Pr(C_{t+1}=0|C_t=i).
\end{align*}
The texts I'm reading treat this as easy enough to leave out the details, but I haven't grasped it yet.

Comment: $$P(C_{t+1}|C_t,C_{t-1},\cdots, C_{1})=P(C_{t+1}|C_t).$$

Really though, you just need to focus on $T_{N(t+1)}$. So work out the various cases for how $T_{N(t+1)}$ relates to $T_{N(t)}$.

Comment: Meyn and tweedie?

Comment: No @Rocky I was asking if that's the book this was coming from

Comment: @Taylor Oh, no. I'm reading from miscellaneous lecture notes online